# Function which returns Sum of all arguments

Tags: python, function, sum, arguments

I want bo create a function which returns sum of all passed arguments.

I found similar problem on forum, but It doesn't work with last case.

```
def sum_all(*args):
    sum = 0

    for num in args:
        if not str(num).isdigit():
            return False
        else:
            sum += int(num)
    return sum
```

This code work with first and second case, but return false on third case.

```
sum_all(2,-3)
# -1
sum_all([3,4,5])
# 12
sum_all(1,2,[3,4,5])
# false
```

How can i make it work? To make it return 15 in last case?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to flatten `*args`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Comment: I get `False` for the second example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of a list, just call the function recursively, example:

```
def sum_all(*args):
  sum = 0
  for num in args:
    if type(num) is list:
      sum += sum_all(*num)
    else:
      sum += int(num)
  return sum
```

Comment: Don't you still need a check for an input that isn't numeric?

Comment: this is simplified, I didn't do entire error handling. I just demonstrated the needed recursion

Answer (score 1):

Can use this

```
def sum_all(*args):
    s = 0
    for a in args:
        if type(a)==list:
            s+=sum(a)
        else:
            s+=int(a)
    return s
print(sum_all(2,-3))
print(sum_all([3,4,5]))
print(sum_all(1,2,[3,4,5]))
```